# JS: Refactor multi-callback function into promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I was wondering if someone knows a good way to refactor the following function into a more promise-esque function:

```
function runProcess(processStarted, processFinished) {
   getProcessId(processStarted)
   doABunchOfAsyncLogic(processFinished)
}
```

It is invoked like this:

```
runPromise(function handleStart(){...}, function handleEnd(){...})
```

Comment: This is an interesting question but comes along with tons of questions. The pattern depends on how these two functions are correlated? Is the first one async too? Is the second one dependent on the result of the first? If the first one is async the Id of it will be given to you synchronously once you invoke it. Do you want to use it to cancel the promise chain? Kind of...

Comment: Please post your actual code so that we can see what your callbacks are really doing

Answer (score 4):

This is not a good use-case for promises, because by its nature you need *two* callbacks: One for starting, one for finishing. But promises are one-offs: Once settled, they can't be re-settled or similar.

You *can* do it, by returning an array of two promises, or an object with the individual promises for "start" and "finish":

```
function runProcess() {
    return {
        start: new Promise(...),
        finish: new Promise(...)
    };
}
```

...but it's not a natural promise use-case.

I'd probably expect the process to *start* during the function call, and only its *end* to be promise-ified.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah, strangely enough this doesn't seem like a great promise use case. I ended up allowing a `handleStart` callback and then returning a promise for the main `processFinished` callback.

Comment: @majorBummer Is there *always* a `handleStart` callback or should it be optional? What does it need to do?